# Determine Current Visual Studio 2013 Test Agent Version

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 and we are trying to run build definition on a remote server with a test agent.

TFS complains that our test agent version is too old:

> No agent found in pool 1 which satisfies the specified demands:
>
> Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.94.0

The question is: how can you tell the current version of the agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it on the Agent pools pagein TFS under Capabilities.

[image]