# TFS 2015 Requires Test Agent with a Certain Version

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

When we are trying to queue a build with some coded UI tests, TFS 2015 complains about test agent not being of the correct version.

> No agent found in pool 1 which satisfies the specified demains:
>
> Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.94.0

[image]

I've downloaded and installed the **[Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48140)**, but I'm not sure if it's the latest possible version we can get.

I'm 100% pretty sure TFS sees our agent.

Is there a way to ensure we have this 1.94.0 version? And where can I find a download link for it? Or maybe, the problem is not with the version?

Comment: Did you investigate [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/lab-management/test-machines/install-configure-test-agents)?

Comment: You need an agent whose version is greater than v1.94, so everything above should work. I have VS2015 installed and agent version is v1.95.3 .

Comment: So, you are saying that I just Need Agents for Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 instead of Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 5? Ok, I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for a build agent which version is equal to 1.94.0 rather than the test agent version. Please download the latest build agent from your TFS web portal and configure it.

Comment: Thank you. you are right. I need to go to the TFS admin panel under /_admin/. Here is a similar question with a screenshot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667507/determine-current-visual-studio-2013-test-agent-version/38688677#38688677

Answer (score 1):

If you are running tests using Build vNext tasks and want to install agents from a local directory, you need to [download Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) - Click on "Tools for Visual Studio 2015" and then select "Agents for Visual Studio 2015" from the left navigation bar.

Or you can add a [Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/visual-studio-test-agent-deployment) task in your build step. This task will deploy “Test Agent” to all the machines and configures them automatically for the automation run.

Comment: Thank you, Cece. I will try your advice soon